# Promissory Note Versus Loan Agreement for Real Estate Investment

Tags: united-states, contract-law, tax-law, real-estate, partnership

I have a friend that has been flipping houses for years and I have an opportunity to invest in one of her upcoming deals and would like to do so.  However, I am not sure what the proper way for me to account for my investment and document the deal is.

I would give her the money at the start and be paid back along with an equivalent portion of the profit when the house is sold.  I see that there are websites such as https://www.legalcontracts.com/contracts/promissory-note-forms/ that offer Promissory Notes and Loan Agreements.  Most of these seem to focus on typical loan with interest.  Can I just add an amendment in the last step that the loan is to be repaid with the agreed upon portion of the profit?  Is there a better type of form to use in this scenario?

Also, how would this affect my tax return.  Clearly, it would be income that I would need to declare, but would it count as capital gains, taxable interest or something else?  Can I wait until tax season to worry about it or would it require some sort of informational return before then?

Comment: Too broad and requesting personal advice. VTC, -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An agreement to carry on economic activity for a share of profits is a general partnership, unless organized otherwise, as a matter of law. You would be well advised to form a limited liability company, in which you would be a co-owner, that would set out the economic terms of the relationship and would be governed by the tax laws applicable to partnerships.

While this could be done in a document labeled a "promissory note" this would be a problem as you could have unlimited liability as the promissory note would probably be interpreted as a general partnership agreement.

Comment: An LLC established as a partnership with the its "pass through" status looks to be exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!